# Generic method isn't choosing the most specific constructor signature?

Tags: c#, generics

When I use a method with a generic parameter to create another object, the generic object isn't selecting the most specific constructor.  That sounds confusing, so here's some sample code to demonstrate what I mean...

Can anyone explain why the output of this program is:

```
guid    <-- easy - no problem here
object  <-- WHY?  This should also be "guid"?!
```

...and how to make the generic `Add<T>` function call the correct constructor of `C`??  Here's the code:

```cs
void Main()
{
    B b = new B();

    C c = new C(Guid.Empty);
    b.Add<Guid>(Guid.Empty);
}

public class B
{
    List<C> cs = new List<C>();
    public void Add<T>(T v) { cs.Add(new C(v)); }
}

public class C
{
    public C(Guid c) { Console.WriteLine("guid"); }
    public C(object c) { Console.WriteLine("object"); }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Overload resolution is done at compile time, not at runtime**. So when you call `new C(v)` from the `Add<T>` method, the compiler doesn't know that `T` will actually be `Guid`, so it uses the only overload that is guaranteed to be compatible, which is `public C(object c)`

Comment: Is it done on a per-class basis?  Because I look at this and I *know* that `T` is a `Guid` because `b.Add<Guid>(...)`.  But if it is on a per-class basis then I can understand, because the `B` class might be in a pre-compiled DLL.  Does that sound like I'm understanding?

Comment: If this were C++ templates, would the more-specific override be called since type-specific code was generated during compile time?

Comment: @MichaelBray, yes, actually for a generic method, it's done on a per-method basis. When the `Add<T>` method is compiled, the compiler doesn't look at how it's called, it just looks at the method itself.

Comment: @ytoledano, I haven't coded in C++ for 10 years, so I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that yes, it would call the more specific overload, since a different method would actually be generated at compile time.

Comment: I checked, it does. If A : B and there are these functions, then this is the precedence: `void f(B *a)`, `template<class T> void f(T *t)`, `void f(A *a)`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: aha...  I tested this by removing the overloaded constructor `C(object c)` and sure enough, it doesn't compile anymore, complaining that it `can't convert from 'T' to 'System.Guid'`.  That makes sense.

Comment: The lesson here is: C# is not C++, and generics are not templates. Generics are part of a *type system*, which is a logical framework in which the compiler makes logical deductions about the meaning of the source code. Templates are much more of a *lexical* system; you can think of the template instantiation as simply substituting in the text and then analyzing the new text from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Generics in C# do not work the same as C++ templates - they are not expanded at compile time based on the usage. A single method is created and the methods called from within it are resolved statically.

Therefore, within `Add`, `v` can be any type, so the only thing known about it is that inherits from `object` so the `object` constructor for `C` is the only candidate.

To get the behaviour you want you'll have to add another overload of `Add` e.g.

```
public void Add(Guid g) { cs.Add(new C(g)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lee and Thomas's answers are correct. To add onto them, I believe that adding constraints to your generics *might* enable it to pick the most specific one. Rewriting your Add method:

```
public void Add<T>(T v) where T : Guid {
  cs.Add(new C(v));
}
```

Of course, now you can only call Add with a Guid, or an extension of Guid. Kind of pointless in retrospect. I think for what you're looking for, you would do a runtime check. `if (v is Guid)` I think...sorry, I'm forgetting what the C# type-check operator is.

Comment: That doesn't even compile - Guid isn't a valid generic type constraint.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I realized Guid was a struct, not a class. A generic definition enforcing a particular struct would be...not a generic at all. Sorry, that wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If one defines a class `Foo<T> where T:SomeClass`, all method bindings and operator overloads will be performed as though `T` was `SomeClass`; in the absence of constraints, they will generally be performed as though it was `Object`.  There is no mechanism by which the type of `T` can be considered when evaluating bindings and overloads.

If one needs to have a few types which behave specially, one could define a private generic interface with one or more methods to perform an operation on type `T`, a private generic class which implements that interface in the "usual" fashion, and private non-generic classes which implement the interface in the fashion appropriate for certain" special types.  The private generic class should hold a static reference to the interface type.  For a non-special class `T`, that reference should refer to an instance of the private generic class.  For special types, that reference should refer to an instance of the "special" class.  Using this approach will require an extra level of virtual dispatch when performing a method which may be "special", but will avoid the need for other run-time type checking based upon `T`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making your code something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    B b = new B();

    C c = new C(Guid.Empty);
    b.Add<Guid>(Guid.Empty);
}

public class B
{
    List<C> cs = new List<C>();
    public void Add<T>(T v) { cs.Add(new C(v)); }
}

public class C<T>
{
    public C(T c) 
    { 
        if(c is Guid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("guid"); }
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("object");
        }
    }
}
```

This version should compile, notice that you have to manually check the types of the generic though

Edit:

This actually won't compile due to the list:

```
List<C> cs = new List<C>();
```

It's not possible to represent your code in a type-safe way. Your choices are to restructure how this works or to do manual casting from `object` in the `C` constructor (or possibly see if `dynamic` will fit your needs)